# How to populate a one2many field from another one2many field in python?

Tags: python-2.7, one-to-many, openerp-7

I have this situation w/c i don't know what to do about it. The case is this: In class **sale_order** I have this definition:

```
...
'sched_lines' : fields.one2many('schedule.schedule','Schedule'),
'factor_lines' : fields.one2many('sale.order.factor','Factor'),
```

So does, in class **account_invoice** i also have this definition:

```
...
'sched_lines' : fields.one2many('schedule.schedule','Schedule'),
'factor_lines' : fields.one2many('sale.order.factor','Factor'),
```

Back to class **sale_order** i override the method **manual_invoice**,

```
    for sale_order in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
        _logger.info("\n\t\t\tFACTOR LINES IN SALE ORDER ... %s"%(str(sale_order.factor_lines)))
        _logger.info("\n\t\t\tHISTORY IN SALE ORDER ... %s"%(str(sale_order.sched_lines)))
        _logger.info("\n\t\t\tSALE ORDER ID ... %s\n\t\t\tIDS ... %s"%(str(sale_order.id),str(ids)))
        inv_id = self.pool.get('account.invoice').search(cr,uid,[('id','in',[new_inv_ids]),('origin','=',sale_order.name)])

        factor_list = self.pool.get('sale.order.factor').search(cr,uid,[('invoice_id','=',inv_id[0])])
        _logger.info("\n\t\t\tfactor_list...%s"%(str(factor_list)))
        factor_lines1 = [factors.id for factors in self.pool.get('sale.order.factor').browse(cr,uid,factor_list,context=context)]
        _logger.info("\n\t\t\tfactor_lines1...%s"%(str(factor_lines1)))

        # cr.execute('select id from sale_order_factor where invoice_id = %s', (tuple(inv_id)))
        #---------------- factor_lines1 = map(lambda x: x[0], cr.fetchall())
        # factor_lines1 = [(1,0,[factors.id for factors in sale_order.factor_lines])]
        #--- _logger.info("\n\t\t\tfactor_lines1...%s"%(str(factor_lines1)))

        self.pool.get('account.invoice').write(cr,uid,inv_id,{
                                                              'sched_ids': [(6,0,[sched.id for sched in sale_order.sched_lines])],
                                                              'factor_lines': [(6,0,[factor.id for factor in sale_order.factor_lines])],#factor_lines1
                                                              })
```

what i can't understand is that this statement **"[(6,0,[factor.id for factor in sale_order.factor_lines])]"** does not work. When i view the invoice it has not populated. It's source, that is the **factor_lines** in sale_order, is not empty. While this statement **"[(6,0,[sched.id for sched in sale_order.sched_lines])]"** works fine. What's inside in **sched_lines** from sale_order is being carried fine. Does anyone can point out what's the missing, if there is any, in my code? I am really stuck in this.

**Any help is very much appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it there is nothing wrong about the code. The mistake is on my declaration of

```
'factor_lines' : fields.one2many('sale.order.factor','Factor'),
```

Instead of pointing it to it's counter part (many2one) in class **sale_order_factor**. It point to different class. By the way, i forgot that my declaration above is not correctly set as seen on the body part of this question, perhaps typo error.